# systemd brings up sshd before networkd, causing no ssh service

Tags: systemd, bridge, sshd

On my Ubuntu 23.04 system, systemd will attempt to bring up sshd before the network's bridge is brought up by systemd-networkd

First it reports: **Cannot assign requested address**

And then: **br0: netdev ready**

```
systemd[1]: Listening on dbus.socket - D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
systemd[730]: ssh.socket: Failed to create listening socket (10.1.0.1:22): s
systemd[1]: ssh.socket: Failed to receive listening socket (10.1.0.1:22): Input/output error
systemd[1]: ssh.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Input/output error
systemd[1]: ssh.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.
systemd[1]: Failed to listen on ssh.socket - OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket.
systemd[1]: Dependency failed for ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
systemd[1]: ssh.service: Job ssh.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
systemd[1]: Listening on uuidd.socket - UUID daemon activation socket.
systemd[1]: Reached target sockets.target - Socket Units.
systemd[1]: systemd-pcrphase-sysinit.service - TPM2 PCR Barrier (Initialization) was skipped because of an unmet condition check (Condition>
systemd[1]: Reached target basic.target - Basic System.
systemd[1]: Started acpid.service - ACPI event daemon.
audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='unit=acpid comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/sys>
systemd[1]: alsa-state.service - Manage Sound Card State (restore and store) was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPath>
systemd[1]: Starting alsa-restore.service - Save/Restore Sound Card State...
systemd[1]: Started anacron.service - Run anacron jobs.
audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='unit=anacron comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/s>
systemd[1]: Starting atopacct.service - Atop process accounting daemon...
anacron[733]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-04-21
systemd[1]: Starting avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
anacron[733]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
systemd[1]: Starting dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus...
kernel: bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
systemd[1]: Started dmesg.service - Save initial kernel messages after boot.
audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='unit=dmesg comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/sys>
avahi-daemon[735]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 115) and group 'avahi' (GID 121).
systemd-networkd[619]: br0: netdev ready
```

Why does systemd not wait until the bridge is up, before doing the sshd service?

My network devices:

```
$ networkctl 
IDX LINK     TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo       loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 enp101s0 ether    enslaved    configured
  3 eno1     ether    enslaved    configured
  4 eno2     ether    routable    configured
  5 br0      bridge   routable    configured
```

I have my network configured with this netplan:

```
# Bridge config
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    # WAN port to cable modem.
    eno2:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
    # Currently not used.
    enx00242788156c:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    # LAN port to WAP
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    # LAN port to switch.
    enp101s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        #- enx00242788156c
        - eno1
        - enp101s0
      addresses:
        - 10.1.0.1/16
```

NOTE: Restarting the sshd service works as expected, because at that time, the bridge is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does systemd not wait until the bridge is up, before doing the sshd service?

You didn't ask it to; 2) all services by default start after sockets.target, so if you did, then delaying them would cause an ordering cycle; 3) it would mostly defeat the point of using a .socket unit instead of just letting sshd itself listen.

Use the `[Socket]` `FreeBind=yes` option to make it possible to bind to not-yet-assigned addresses without needing to impose delays.

Comment: I have both `/usr/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket` and `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket` and neither has `FreeBind=yes` in it. Is this a mistake by the maintainers of the openssh-server package?

Comment: No, because the original sockets as distributed by the package do not specify an exact address to bind to – they bind to `0.0.0.0` and `[::]`, so they don't need this option. *You* need this option because *you* have customized ssh.socket to bind to a specific address.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the option to `/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/addresses.conf`  seems to have worked.